# Remote file access (Mac)

Tags: mac, ssh, file-sharing

I have a Mac mini at home that I can SSH into and access via VNC (over SSH).  What's the best way to transfer files from the Mac mini to my local machine.  I assume there is a way to do this in Terminal but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to your Mac Mini using SFTP with [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/).

[image: Cyberduck SFTP]

Answer (score 4):

from your local machine:

```
scp acct_name@your.macmini:/path/to/file local_file
```

Comment: scp++ (I can't just write "scp++" so I had to add this text as filler)

Answer (score 2):

One word: [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/mac)

Answer (score 2):

`scp` is easy and great for quick copies. If you're looking for bigger copying jobs to synchronize directories or multiple files, learn about `rsync`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it over the Terminal, you could use the `scp` command-line utility that transfers files over SSH. If you look at the manpage for `scp` you will find out examples on how to use it.